# How do i find all possible combinations of "I" and "l" in a 30 character string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find all the combinations of "I" (capital i) and "l" (lowercase L) in a string that is 30 characters total for example: `"lIlIIllIllIIIlIlllIlIIIIIllIIl"`

i tried using itertools product and it keeps giving me `<generator object permutations at 0x1014969a8>`

```
import itertools

ext = itertools.product('Il', repeat=30)

print(ext)
```

i expected it to output `"lIlIIllIllIIIlIlllIlIIIIIllIIl"` and more but it gives me `<generator object permutations at 0x1014969a8>`

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The product() function returns an generator, not the actual data.

try making it as list to print:

```
print(list(ext))
```

or

```
print(["".join(c) for c in ext])
```

Note: With a length of 30, this will attempt to print 1073741824 elements which is a bit too much for the console.  You may want to try it with a smaller number first.